# not able to include angular js file in ejs file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, ejs

I am using express js framework. I am not able to include javascript file in ejs page.

//This is my index.ejs page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`
 <head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src= "order.js"></script>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
 </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
 <div class="container">

   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead><tr>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
   </tr></thead>
   <tbody><tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{ user.fName }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.lName }}</td>
   </tr></tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

//This is my JavaScript page order.js which should connect to index.ejs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 angular.module('myApp', []).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello World!';  
   $scope.fName = '';
    $scope.lName = '';
    $scope.passw1 = '';
    $scope.passw2 = '';
    $scope.users = [
    { fName:'Hege',lName:"Pege" },
    { fName:'Kim',lName:"Pim" },
    { fName:'Sal',lName:"Smith" },
    { fName:'Jack',lName:"Jones" },
    { fName:'John',lName:"Doe" },
    { fName:'Peter',lName:"Pan" }
    ];
 })
```

I am not able to display the data here {{ user.fName }}. Could someone please help.

Comment: provide the full html page or check whether controller and app spelled correctly in html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src= "order.js"></script>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<div class="container">

  <div ><% include orders %></div>
  <div ><% include orders %></div>
</div>

</body>
 
</html> @mannivannan

Comment: thats the html code @manivannan

Comment: angular.js is not included in the page. Look in your browser console and error will say `angular is undefined`

Comment: @charlietfl how do i do that? this is my first angular js program. so new to it.

Comment: this is what my browser console shows Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: download angular or use a cdn version ...add script tag pointing at that resource url. 404 is server side problem

Comment: now i am getting angular is undefined message in console. @charlietfl. what do i do now?

Comment: include angular in page before your code that depends on angular

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please type the command to do that?

Comment: download it...add script tag that points to it

Answer (score 0):

You have to include angular in your HTML inside the head in a script tag :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src= "anularpath/angular.js"></script>
```

you can use angular cdn in your case if you dont have the file locally like this :

```
<head>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.0/angular.min.js"></script>
   <title><%= title %></title>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
```

and you should move your order.js file script tag to the bottom of the body right before you close the body tag. like this :

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src= "order.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```